# each process requires 2 MB memory in Android?

Tags: android, memory

I was reading this great article talking about how to build more efficient Android apps:http://blog.azoft.com/android-application-development-tips/.

Those tips are really helpful. But I don't quite sure about this one:

"**Since each process requires 2MB** and might be restarted when foreground apps need memory, make sure the services are short-lived."

Is that real that each process requires 2 MB memory in Android please?

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-do-i-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html :

> Before you decide to create a new process, you need to understand the memory implications. To illustrate the consequences of each process, consider that an empty process doing basically nothing has an extra memory footprint of about 1.4MB, as shown by the memory information dump below.

From 1.4MB for doing basically nothing to doing anything at all useful, the 600k extra to get to 2MB seems plausible.

See also: [Is there a minimal heap size for Android versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14375947/49489)