# "Cannot draw recycled bitmaps" if I invoke recycle() inside onDestroy()

Tags: java, android, exception, bitmap, garbage-collection

I have two activities: `MainActivity` and `Activity2`.

The MainActivity simply open the seconds one through Intent.

To return to `MainActivity` from the `Activity2` I press the "back" button.

When I do these steps, the App crashes:

- open the App: `MainActivity` appears
- start the Intent: the `Activity2` appears
- press the "back" button: the `MainActivity` appears
- start the `Intent`: my App crashes because of this error:

  > IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps

MainActivity.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, ImageView> entry : mapImageViews.entrySet()) {
        ImageView imageView = entry.getValue();
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            if(bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            bitmapDrawable = null;
            bitmap = null;
        }
        imageView.setOnClickListener(null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        imageView = null;
        drawable = null;
    }
    mapImageViews.clear();
    mapImageViews = null;
}
```

Since the application uses high resolution images (already adapted with `BitmapFactory` and `inSampleSize`), to avoid memory leaks I invoke `recycle()` in the `onDestroy()` method.

As I learned by reading lots of SO answers and on the Web, calling `recycle()` on bitmap let they to be garbage collected early.

But many other posts advise against invoking `recycle()`, or at least advise doing it only when you are sure that the bitmap is no longer needed in the Activity, that is in the `onDestroy()` method.

Now I'm a little worried about what I've learned about it because if I remove the `recycle()` the error no longer happens.

The error occurs on a device with Android `4.4.2`, but it does not occur on a device with Android `6.0` and on `Nexus 7` (Android `5.1.1`).

- Is the problem about the activities' stack?
- Does the GC is trying to free the bitmap's memory too late? In case of this, how to definitively destroy the Activity and ALL its contents?
- There is any difference between these two Android versions?
- Or there is something I'm missing/wrong?

Comment: Have you tried my answer given below?

Comment: If `mapImageViews` is not static, nulling everything makes no sense and more like cargo cult than actual cleanup.

Comment: @Miha_x64 can you better explain your comment please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for recycle

> The bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it will throw an exception if
>   getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and will draw nothing. This
>   operation cannot be reversed, so it should only be called if you are
>   sure there are no further uses for the bitmap.

I cant see how you are assigning your `bitmaps` to your `ImageView`, but I assume you are trying to reuse the bitmaps when you start the intent again after they have been `recycled`.  I only ran into the exception if I was using `android:src=`.  If I set the `ImageView` bitmap using the following in `oncreate`, it ran fine on all targets you listed without throwing an exception.

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lake_park));
```

I highly recommend using glide to work with images.
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: If you don't want to use a 3rd party library then try using https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference for bitmaps with LRU or disk cache as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap

Comment: @MatthewWilliams I just tested the same behaviour: if I remove the `android:src` the exception does not happen. Now, did you know why? I suppose that it's because setContentView invokes getPixels()/setPixels() on the ImageView defined with `android:src` but it's recycled; instead defining the new bitmap through code in `oncreate` these methods aren't invoked. Isn't true?

Comment: Yeah I think what you are saying is right.  I can't say for sure, but it seems the `Drawable` assigned to an `ImageView` with `android:src` is not recreated (if recycled) when you start the activity again.  I assume that `Drawable` is allocated only once at the start of the program?

Answer (score 2):

try changing your `onDestroy` method like below

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, ImageView> entry : mapImageViews.entrySet()) {
        ImageView imageView = entry.getValue();
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            if(bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            bitmapDrawable = null;
            bitmap = null;
        }
        imageView.setOnClickListener(null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        imageView = null;
        drawable = null;
    }
    mapImageViews.clear();
    mapImageViews = null;

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Also see this: [How to recycle and reuse images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6648194/4079010) in an effective way.

Comment: Why should I do this?

Comment: Because You're calling the super method before recycling the bitmap and you take the Images Reference from the ImageViews which are destroyed when the super onDestroy got called.

Comment: So, the super.onDestroy() creates others reference of those ImageViews?

Comment: @user2342558 No, when the super got called it destroy all the views references attached to the activity/fragment

Comment: If it's true, why on an Android 6.0 device it works without exception?

Comment: @user2342558 because of [Memory Management](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview). See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375947/is-there-a-minimal-heap-size-for-android-versions

Comment: So, the cause is that the device with Android 4.4.2 has a lower memory heap and then the GC act after the Activity is destroyed? Instead in the device with Android >5 the GC does not act because the memory heap isn't reached, leaving them in the memory?

Comment: @user2342558 yep, upto some extent you're right. With the increase in OS versions they are reducing given memory limit to each app. Recently in Android 10 they have introduced Scoped storage as additional step.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think you don't have to do this manually.

If Activity2 only has 1 image and already resize I think recycle can't help much if you really face memory issue.

And according the this doc only API level lower than 10 is recommended to use recycle(), and the ratio of user are quite small.
`On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, using recycle() is recommended.` 
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory

And I would like to recommend use third party image library as they can free you from do this meaningless things to let you focus on more important part of your app.

Comment: The documentation recommends to use recycle() for Android API level <=10, but it does not discourage its use with API > 10. In other many SO answers, it's suggesting to use recycle() in my manner to free bitmap resource when the GC acts.

Comment: Yes, it don't reveal recommend or not when API > 10 but I think it's not that important to do so if it's only benefit to early GC(If it's important for all version it will not indicate the `On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower`). And it's require lots of boilerplate code and hard to read and maintain as well. If we can leverage on other library to do that, why not? ^^