# Enable android:largeHeap in Android 4, and disable it in Android 2.3

Tags: android

Currently, I have a piece of code, which is designed to run both in Android 2.3 and 4+

The code will perform much better (Where it will not have OutOfMemory exception most of the time), if `android:largeHeap` is being applied in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
    android:largeHeap="true"
```

Currently, my `android:minSdkVersion` need to set to 15 instead of 10 (Android 2.3). If not, `android:largeHeap` is not allowable in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

**Within single APK, how possible I can set**

- Use `android:largeHeap` option if I were in Android 4+
- Do not use `android:largeHeap` option if I were in Android 2.3

Comment: You could refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can also disable large heap in Honeycomb and enable it in ICS or JB. Just a little hacky or something. Here's what I tried.

Before we proceed, change your Build target to Honeycomb, Jelly Bean or ICS so we can put `android:largeHeap` attribute. Also, you can set `android:minSdkVersion` to `API 10`.

Android `API 10` doesn't support large heap.

1. Create a folder `values-v14` in `res` folder
2. I created `bools.xml` in `values-v14`
3. Put this value in `bools.xml` of `values-v14`

`<bool name="largeheap">true</bool>`

boolean value for `values` > `bools.xml` or `values-[API VERSION]` > `bools.xml` to disable large-heap in different API Version or by default.

```
<bool name="largeheap">false</bool>
```

Change the value of `android:largeHeap` to `@bool/largeheap` instead of hardcoded `true` or `false`

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
                ....
</application>
```

I tested this code by making a memory leak application or just load a Huge bitmaps, and, its working!

Good Luck!

Comment: Nevermind the haters, i would add this to your post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions

Answer (score 9):

Keep the `android:largeHeap="true"` attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. This should be ignored for versions that don't support it. Then, to support older versions, set the heap size using the `VMRuntime` class (via reflection, if necessary).

More on this topic: [How to increase heap size of an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

1. 1.Build project with target Android 3.0 (API 11) or above.
           (Project properties - Android - Project Build Target - select above API level 11)
2. in Manifest file, Change the uses-sdk value as following

   < uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="10"
       android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

For prior versions of Android 3.0, you can use VMRuntime class for memory manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have incorrect target sdk in **project.properties** file, check it out and change target to your AndroidManifest`s targetSdk (15) and rebuild project.

project.properties

```
# Project target.
target=15
```

P.S. I tryed add android:largeHeap to my Project (minSdk = 7, targetSdk = 17) compiled and run normally on all Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please change project properties:

In project Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target -> Google API, API level 19 (or any other you need) :)

So your can leave your minimum SDK option without change, for example 8 :)