# OutOfMemory Exception when publishing message over Redis

Tags: android, json, memory, redis, heap-memory

I want to publish a JSON message to a Redis server. This JSON message contains a Base64 encoded audio file and the raw file is around 2.5 MB (which may change further depending on the duration of the audio file). I want to publish this encoded audio file as a JSON message to Redis using an android application. The following is the piece of code I have used:

```
JSONObject servicedData=receivedJSON.getJSONObject("data");
long dataPublished=jedisConnection.publish(queryNo, servicedData.toString());
```

I create a JSON object using an android application and extract the data part of it (which contains the encoded audio file) and then publish this to a channel. This code works fine for smaller files but throws an out of memory exception whenever the file size exceeds 2MB. The following is the error log I get:

[image]

After doing a lot of research, I figured out that a string uses the device's heap to create the object and I should use a json parser to read the json in chunks but I can't do it as I finally have to publish the entire json as string. Any ideas/help on how I can accomplish this will be really appreciated.

Comment: The data contains the audio file (base64 encoded)

Comment: "data" is the JSON key and its value is the audio file as a string

Comment: try these solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918028/enable-androidlargeheap-in-android-4-and-disable-it-in-android-2-3

Comment: if it dose not work tell me !!

Comment: Yes, it is working for files upto 2.5 MB now. Just for my knowledge, upto what heap sizes can the phone handle?