# android largeheap equated to true based on devices

Tags: android, android-largeheap

I want to add in my manifest  `android:largeheap="true"` based on some devices. Mostly devices running probably os 5.1 and below.Because alot of my clients are using samsung s3 , chinese , indian , pakistani phones.And I am getting lots of crashes in my firebase console. However this issue is not faced on top notch devices like google pixel samsung s8 etc.
How can I detect which devices i run largeheap, and how i run it on those devices only? I do not want to run it on devices i dont need to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable android:largeHeap in Android 4, and disable it in Android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918028/enable-androidlargeheap-in-android-4-and-disable-it-in-android-2-3)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't set this flag depending on the device. That's the true. But you can set it depending on OS version, screen size and etc. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918028/enable-androidlargeheap-in-android-4-and-disable-it-in-android-2-3) answer to see how it can be done.