# android version condition for largeheap

Tags: android, android-manifest, react-native

I'm trying to use `largeheap: true` in the `AndroidManifest` file, and I found this answer
[Enable android:largeHeap in Android 4, and disable it in Android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918028/enable-androidlargeheap-in-android-4-and-disable-it-in-android-2-3)

but the problem is I always get the errors

```
/*/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:38:28-41: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'largeHeap' with value '@values/bools').

/*/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:32: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'largeHeap' with value '@values/bools').
```

I created 2 files `bools.xml`
first one in `*/android/app/src/main/res/values/bools.xml`
with value `<bool name="largeheap">true</bool>`
and the 2nd one in `*/android/app/src/main/res/values-v23/bools.xml` with value `<bool name="largeheap">false</bool>` (for api 23 and above)

not sure what I am missing, why the AndroidManifest won't find the resource to match the line `android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap"`

is there anything else I need to do beside the `android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap"` in the `AndroidManifest` file ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error, I can see that android complains about `@values/bools` and your question is showing another line: `android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap"`.

I created a new app project and reproduced your case. This worked for me:

Use this in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap"`

And make sure your `bools.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="largeheap">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Also try to clean and rebuild your project after that.

Comment: Awesome! so I was missing the additional stuff (beside `<bool name="largeheap">true</bool>`), thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!