# Android - Java can't read the whole JSON file

Tags: java, android, json

I issue some problems with my Apps code to read JSON files.
So my App downloads the json files from my server and then uses [this AsyncTask](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Myself5/KCS_Farbrechner/master/KCS%20Farbrechner/src/main/java/de/myself5/farbrechner/JSONArrayAsyncTask.java) to read them.

This works fine for the smaller json file (about 2KB) but the big one (which is about 1.3MB in size) only loads the first lines.

I am not certainly sure what is causing the Problem, I tought about Strings not being able to store that much characters but then I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method) that the maximum of Numbers is around 2 billion (which should not be exeeded by that json File).
I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your Async Task task code, it is complicated to help without having that

Comment: This may be a limitation of `android.util.Log` truncating your "printed" content, not necessarily a problem with your app not reading an entire file. If you are curious, try writing to file instead of `Log`.

Comment: Isn't that what I already do? Downloading the file in JSONDownloader and then reading from it in the JSONArrayAsyncTask?
EDIT: Oh you mean the Debug Line? I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Hum intresting. If I log it to a file, I can see that the whole json file get read. However, this implies that something is wrong with the line where the JSONObject is getting created JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString().trim());
as it does not reach the Log statement after the creating, however it ends the Async Task as my Progress Dialog Dissapears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my error. It was not caused by the String being to short, but by the JSON containing errors (which I did not expect, as it was created by an tool).
Thanks for your help anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Raghav's info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369204/4625407), and how it relates to Ted's info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369300/4625407), you're likely being limited by the available heap to your application.

Comment: So there is no way to work around this? One should think I'm not the first person in the world who tries reading a 1.3MB JSON file in Android :( Also, when the file is 1.3MB, with a total length of 1,303,636 Characters, why doesnt it fit a 16MB Heap whichs max String lenght is  2,147,483,647 and instead only loads the first 4065 (according to a Log line in the Code) Characters?

Answer (score 0):

Working with big JSON files, you should persist the file and then read it.

I'm assuming that JSON files have much more information that a simple API HTTP request.

Comment: Thats what I do actually. I download the json file from my server in the JSONDownloader class, and then read it on the JSONArrayAsyncTask.

Comment: @ChristianOder if is limited to the available heap, try to paginate the requests, or split into smaller files, is that possible?

Comment: Already fixed it, my JSON was broken (Stupid me). Lessons Learned, never 100% trust online tools.

Comment: Ahahaha! Glad you found a solution