# Kotlin String max length? (Kotlin file with a long String is not compiling)

Tags: java, string, kotlin, string-length

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369204/11377112) Java can hold up to 2^31 - 1 characters. I was trying to do benchmarking and stuffs, so I tried to create a large amount of string and write it to a file like this:

```kotlin
import java.io.*

fun main() {
    val out = File("ouput.txt").apply { createNewFile() }.printWriter()
    sequence {
        var x = 0
        while (true) {
            yield("${++x} ${++x} ${++x} ${++x} ${++x}")
        }
    }.take(5000).forEach { out.println(it) }
    out.close()
}
```

And then the `output.txt` file contains like this:

```kotlin
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
// ... 5000 lines
```

And then I copied all the contents of the file into a string for some benchmarking of some functions, so this is how it looks:

```kotlin
import kotlin.system.*

fun main() {
    val inputs = """
        1 2 3 4 5
        6 7 8 9 10
        11 12 13 14 15
        16 17 18 19 20
        21 22 23 24 25
        // ... 5000 lines
        24986 24987 24988 24989 24990
        24991 24992 24993 24994 24995
        24996 24997 24998 24999 25000

    """.trimIndent()
    measureNanoTime {
        inputs.reader().forEachLine { line ->
            val (a, b, c, d, e) = line.split(" ").map(String::toInt)
        }
    }.div(5000).let(::println)
}
```

> The total character count of the file/string is 138894
>
> String can hold up to 2147483647

**But the Kotlin code does not compile (last file)** It throws compilation error:

```kotlin
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated
// more lines
The root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ByteVector.putUTF8(ByteVector.java:246)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.TransformationMethodVisitor.visitEnd(TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.endVisit(FunctionCodegen.java:971)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UTF8 string too large
```

Here is the total log of exception with stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/Animeshz/1a18a7e99b0c0b913027b7fb36940c07

Comment: The maximum length of a string in general and the maximum length of a string constant in a compiled class may be different.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what does that mean? It wasn't compile time constant iirc, as it was not a `const val`, am I right?

Comment: If it appears in quotes in source code, it's a compile time constant.

Comment: I meant quotes and triple quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is limit in java class file, length of string constant must fit in 16 bits ie. 65535 bytes (not characters) is max length of string in source code.

[The class File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7)