# max amount of data a String can hold in java

Tags: java, string, limit

I have read [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369204/14421006), but what would happend if you keep adding strings to the same variable? after reching the max_value. Assuming the computer have enough resources to do this.
For example:

```
 String s="";

 double n=Math.pow(2,32);

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
   s=s+'x';
 }
```

Comment: Probably throws an OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Is there something stopping you from running your code in order to see what happens?

Comment: @Abra: doing this stepping by 1 will take hours at least, maybe days. OP: if you step by say 10-100 chars at once you will get quicker but equally representative results. Note as covered in the older and more complete dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/ in Java 9 up Strings containing only Latin1 chars occupy less storage than others, so you might want to test both Latin1 and non-Latin1 cases. Also note `long` can represent pow(2,32) and compute it more easily as `1L<<32`, but `int` cannot count to this value, so use `long i`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I did was:

```java
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s = new String(new char[Integer.MAX_VALUE-1]);
        s = s + ".";
    }
```

What I obtained was:

```java
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

Comment: I think you will find it blows up on the `new char[]`, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the limit is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` characters, however, some JVMs can't actually create an array of length `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so you can find a practical limit is a few characters less.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        try {
            char[] chars = new char[Integer.MAX_VALUE - i];
            System.out.println("Created new char[MAX_VALUE-" + i + "]");
            break;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError oome) {
            if (i == 0)
                oome.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

on my Windows 10 Java 8 update 251 machine prints

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at A.main(A.java:12)

Created new char[MAX_VALUE-2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm going to investigate more about the 'OutOfMemoryError'. Now, theoretically speaking, what would happend if the JVM can create such array? after the array reach the Integer.MAX_VALUE it will throw me an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: It seems that OutOfMemoryError extends VirtualMachineError, so, correct me if I'm wrong the error will not appear in a theoretical enviorment, where there is no JVM involved, I know i'm being a little abstract with the question, but there is a question in one of my classes that is something like the one I asked, and can't find information anywhere