# Canvas crash on height 2500*2500

Tags: android

Hy,
why canvas crash me if i make width*height (2500*2500) i am wonder i dont know why :(

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)

This is small pictures but how can i make if i want to process a biger pictures, or how can i find the maximum border of the canvas max size ? Pleas help and help solve problems. I think the width* hight i cant change, because its opengls problem but i think i cant find the border but i dont know how?

Comment: Have you calculated how large the bitmap for a 2500x2500 ARGB canvas is?  Nearly 25MB.  More than the heap size on most devices.  You will have to reduce you size and/or colour depth.

Comment: [(Height in pixels) x (length in pixels) x (bit depth)] / 8 / 1024 = image size in kilobytes (KB).

Comment: how can i calculate for how much is the larger picture ? (width and height) or how can i slove a problem, pleas help..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions

Comment: in android max size for canvas i want calculate if,. if you want test my app if you write it inside in textbox(2500*2500) it will crash, i want protect it about this crash :( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slikar.slika&hl=sl

Comment: you have to just check the input and if its too high then give them a toast or something and reset the input

Answer (score 1):

As I remember  Android hardware must at least support 2048x2048.

For OpenGL I used:

```
int[] maxSize = new int[1];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
```

- For Nexus 4 it equals to `4096`
- For Sansung 2 it equals to `4096`

But sure it should be different from device to device