# Android Switch Statement Crashing

Tags: java, android, debugging, switch-statement

I created a switch statement in my android java file, the switch will set a drawable file to an imageView depending on the corresponding 'rating'. When it runs it crashes and says that it ran out of memory however I have allocated the virtual device 3000mb and the code runs fine until I input a value for the switch to compare

**Debugger Error Message**

```
1752-1752/com.cs13ppz.virtualgallery E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cs13ppz.virtualgallery, PID: 1752
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
            at com.cs13ppz.virtualgallery.ArtworkLibrary.ratingBar(ArtworkLibrary.java:55)
            at com.cs13ppz.virtualgallery.ArtworkLibrary.onCreate(ArtworkLibrary.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Switch Statement**
ImageView ratingBar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
        int rating = 5;

```
switch(rating){
    case 0: {
        ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star0);
    }
    case 1: {
        ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star05);
    }
    case 2: {
        ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star1);
    }
    case 3:
            ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star15);
            break;
    case 4:
            ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star2);
            break;
    case 5:
            ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star25);
            break;
    case 6:
            ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star3);
            break;
    case 7:
            ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star35);
            break;
    case 8:
            ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star4);
            break;
    case 9:
            ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star45);
            break;
    case 10:
            ratingBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star5);
            break;
    }
```

By the way all the images that are being assigned to each case are very small, only about 15kb each. I was also wondering if there would be an easier way to implement this?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but is there a reason you don't have any breaks after conditions 0, 1 and 2? You really need them, or the code will 'fall through' https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: I do now, i had just edited the code and forgot to add them back in

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related with the `switch` per se, you are running out of memory due to the size of your images. Android process have a maximum amount of memory allocated to them by the OS (the heap). This memory has nothing to do with the storage space of the device.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9940415/2029566) answer shows heap sizes for some devices.

Comment: Really the images are only 20kb each, and even if I delete all the other cases and try with 1 case it still fails. I had a look at the link and have tried the android:setheapsize(bigger) thing but it still didn't work