# 40+ ImageButtons on one screen?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, imagebutton

For last 10+ hours I try to get a large (40+) amount of images (in ImageButton format) on a single Android screen without out of memory errors. The activity I work on is an image picker for a coloring book app. Images are of various sizes in the range of (500 to 1200)x(500 to 1200), PNGs (if that matters).

I have tried:

- Horizontal Scroll View with images added from the code. The result is slow (I do it on UI thread) and consumes large memory space.
- Horizontal Scroll View with images added from the code via AsyncThread. The result is fast but still consumes large memory space. **I like the user experience of this one the most!**
- Grid View and List View - both are very choppy (testing on first Nexus 7). Memory usage is better.

What I am considering

- View Pager - first results look better than Grid View from performance perspective (I have not completed it to the moment to assess the memory usage but it should be better from what I understand). Yet, I dislike the user experience and prefer a scrollable list of all images.
- Conversion of my resources to JPG (will that get rid of Transparency byte?)
- Downsizing the images to max 500x500px

None of the solutions seems as good as the Android Photo Gallery app available on all devices. This experience is what I would love to mirror. No idea how this is done though :(

Two questions.

1. What is the best way to get such thing (40+ Images scrollable on single screen) done? Is it really ViewPager? ScrollView with AsyncTask and well thought images resolution? Something I have not tried yet?
2. What is the memory limit I should try to keep below? Looking at [Android heap size on different phones/devices and OS versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions) it seems to be 256 MB, is that fair assumption?

Thanks. Have a great weekend!

PS. On iOS all works like charm when I add all the buttons into a scroll view :(

Comment: Consider using an external library such as `Universal Image Loader`, or `Picasso` (http://square.github.io/picasso/) if you are loading them from the internet.

Comment: 40 images at the same time or not? It does matter. It would be great if you show screen of your app.

Comment: Why are you trying to load a 500x500 image onto a button? Create a thumbnail at a more reasonable size (perhaps 50x50) and use that. Load the full size image when it's selected.

Comment: Check the android source code for the gallery app. And @Hobo Sapiens is correct, there's really no reason to load full images until one is selected

Comment: You seem to have some contradictions in your question. You mention `ViewPager` but say "Yet, I dislike the user experience and prefer a scrollable list of all images.". Then you mention "...the Android Photo Gallery app..." and say "This experience is what I would love to mirror.". Previously you mention using a Nexus 7...well I have a Nexus 7 and the Photos app which came pre-installed uses a `ViewPager` when viewing images as full screen. How come you love the built-in Photos app but dislike the UX of `ViewPager`?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I highly appreciate your input!

ViewPager vs Gallery App - I like the presentation of multiple photos. They seem to load in the background so I will probably keep the AsyncTask based loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some basic calculations reveals your problem:

40+ images at 1200x1200 = approx 57MB, the comments are correct you need to subsample (i.e. thumbnail) the images or use a library such as the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). Converting to JPG doesn't matter. That is a compressed storage format, the memory required to display the pixels remains the same.

There is a Android Developers article on [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) with sample code. The following steps are covered in more detail in the article [Android Bitmap Loading for Efficient Memory Usage](https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/android-bitmap-loading).

The basic steps in loading a large bitmap are:

- Determine the required size (from a known size or determining the
  size of the target View).
- Use the **BitmapFactory** class to get the bitmap’s size (set *inJustDecodeBounds* in **BitmapFactory.Options** to true).
- Calculate the subsampling value and pass it to the **BitmapFactory.Options** setting *inSampleSize*.
- Use the **BitmapFactory** to load a reduced size bitmap.

Comment: Thanks I believe that will be the way to proceed. Do you know if it makes any difference to use JPGs vs PNGs (transparency byte?) or use ARGB4444 / RGB565 vs ARGB8888 when creating a Bitmap?