# What's wrong with this inSampleSize calculating method for Bitmaps? Out of memory

Tags: java, android, bitmap

In my app i'm iterating through URLs of images, decoding and putting them in an `ArrayList<Bitmap>`.

They may vary greatly in size, so i'm doing a "pre-decode" with the `inJustDecodeBounds = true` option to calculate the necessary `inSampleSize` value for the actual decode.

See my method for this below, i hope it's not too hard to understand. Basically i'm aiming for a size similar to the screen size of the device.

```
for (Element e: posts) {
    if (!e.id().equals("")) {
        //preparing decode
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        input = new URL(e.url).openStream();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
        input.close();

        //setting inSampleSize if necessary
        int picPixels = options.outWidth * options.outHeight;
        int picScreenRatio = picPixels / screenPixels;
        if (picScreenRatio > 1) {
            int sampleSize = picScreenRatio % 2 == 0 ? picScreenRatio : picScreenRatio + 1;
            options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
        }

        //actual decode
        input = new URL(e.url).openStream();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
        input.close();

        picList.add(pic);
    }
}
```

Code for calculating `screenPixels`:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point screenSize = new Point();
display.getSize(screenSize);
int screenPixels = screenSize.x * screenSize.y;
```

I'm going through ~60 images and around 40 my app crashes with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

As i understand, with `inJustDecodeBounds = true` there's no memory allocated, and if my method is correct (i believe it is), very big images get very big `inSampleSize`s, so i don't know what could be the problem.

Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter that you use inSampleSize you can't easily hold 60 bitmaps as large as your screen in memory.

Assuming a fullhd screen you get about `1920*1080*60*4` bytes.

Thats roughly **500 MB of data**. 
You need to somehow change your bitmap loading logic.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions) answer you can find out how much memory you can count with. It differs for various devices.

But always try to make you app as memory efficient as possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the problem, dunno why i haven't thought of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sample size must be a power of two. From the documentation:

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original
>   image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is
>   the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single
>   pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an
>   image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the
>   number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the
>   decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will
>   be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.

Here's a good trick from the [Android - Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java) library on how to find the best sample size for bitmaps:

```
    int findBestSampleSize(int actualWidth, int actualHeight, int desiredWidth, int desiredHeight) {
        double wr = (double) actualWidth / desiredWidth;
        double hr = (double) actualHeight / desiredHeight;
        double ratio = Math.min(wr, hr);
        float n = 1.0f;
        while ((n * 2) <= ratio) {
            n *= 2;
        }

        return (int) n;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is notoriously hard to get image manipulation right on Android. I would recommend that you use an established Image Management Library like [Facebook's Fresco](http://frescolib.org/):

https://github.com/facebook/fresco

An example from their docs:

> Fresco's Drawees show a placeholder for you until the image has loaded and automatically show to the image when it arrives. When the image goes off-screen, it automatically releases its memory.

Also:

> Apps using Fresco can run even on low-end devices without having to constantly struggle to keep their image memory footprint under control.