# What kind of memory does Android Studio's Memory Monitor show?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-memory

We are using the built-in [memory monitor](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html) in android studio to walk through the memory usage of our mobile game. But the result shows that our game is allocated with only tens of MB memory. However, as far as we have known, our game consumes 200 MB+ memory when it is running on PC(via PC platform for the game).  So my question is what type of memory is the memory monitor showing?

PS: I have very limited knowledge on android memory system :)

[image]

Comment: What type of device are you running for that screeenshot? If it's RAM, 32MB doesn't seem like a lot for a phone.

Comment: My device is Xiaomi 3

Comment: go through this link..http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html

Comment: @AmitVaghela - that is the link already in the first line of the post

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are seeing is called the heap. This amount can change amongst various Android devices and can be increased in applications running on API Level 11+ by adding `android:largeHeap="true"` on the `<application>` element in the manifest to request a larger-than-normal heap size.

See this post for additional information: [Android heap size on different phones/devices and OS versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions)