# Android Emulator Error resizing partition e2fsck failed

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

**[ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKewy.png)**

I want to run my first android app i'm getting error with Emulator,
plz help me.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621715/error-with-android-studio-cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator). And also consider adding some more relevant tags to your question.

Comment: this link helps me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877508/error-resizing-partition-e2fsck-failed-with-exit-code-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877508/error-resizing-partition-e2fsck-failed-with-exit-code-8)

Answer (score 0):

We can fix the issue as follows

1. Try to increase the VM Heap size to 512 MB which is the minimum required size.

if it doesn't work

2. Increase your emulator RAM=1024 MB and Internal storage =550 MB.

If these two doesn't work then finally create a new virtual device instead of using the old one.

Thank you.

Comment: <<VM Heap size to 512 MB>> where didi you find this value? It seems the minimum is 16 (for older devices), here more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions

Comment: go to /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions and change Xmx  or Environment Variables had a System Variable called _JAVA_OPTIONS with the value -Xms256m -Xmx512m, after changing this to -Xms256m -Xmx1024m the max heap size increased accordingly....Thank you

Comment: so in the point 1 of your answer you are talking about java VM of the machine where android studio run, in the point 2 you are talking about emulator configuration, please edit the answer and specify. Also the emulator has a VM heap size configuration of the dex VM...