# ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8

Tags: android, android-emulator, exit-code, android-studio-2.2, run-app

I'm new to android studio. When I try to run my first programme in android studio on the emulator, I get this error.

I have searched through other comments and have also tried decreasing my build.gradle from 24.0.0 to 23.0.3 as shown below, but it still doesn't work. I'm running on Nexus 5X API 23.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
}
```

The error shown is:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

```
Output:
emulator: WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 756 M to 800 M ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had the same issue after updating Android SDK tools package to version 25.2.2. To fix the problem i've restarted Android SDK Manager and then created new virtual device instead of using the old one.

Comment: I am trying this on Jenkins AWS linux ec2 instance ? so how to upgrade it using jenkins

Comment: Just creating a new avd with lower api and different device works for me.

Comment: My "Android SDK Tools" package version is : 25.2.5 and i have the same error

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an "old" question, but the following command solved the problem for me:

```
./emulator -data /sdk/path/here/system-images/android-API/default/x86/userdata.img -avd your_avd_name
```

where API is the api level you want to use. I found that this is only needed for API<20

**Note:** I had that problem with `libstdc++`, so I had to use the `LD_PRELOAD` envvar. I removed it in the example, so for me, the complete command looks like this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ./emulator -data /home/username/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-API/default/x86/userdata.img -avd Whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same type of problem after installing an update to one the SDK platforms, except my output log contained more than complaints. It contained a possible solution to the problem. See the log below.

```
emulator: WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 769 M to 770 MERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8

Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
 - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android SDK Tools" checkbox
 - Click "OK"
Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Nougat is running.
Waiting for emulator to be ready...
```

### Solution 1: Update the SDK Tools

1. Open Android SDKs and Tools window.
2. Go to the Tools tab (the name of this tab has changed).
3. Expand the Android SDK Tools group and make sure you select the
   latest available version.
4. Click Apply Changes.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Possible problem with this solution:**

You may run into a new problem by following this solution. When you run the emulator it will do a cold boot and ask you for a decryption password. If you don't provide the right password, it will display a black screen and then tell you that the decryption failed.

[image]
[image]

So this did not work in my case, but your mileage may vary.

### Solution 2: Factory reset the emulator

I don't use Android Studio. I use Xamarin with Visual Studio. Installing the Xamarin Device Manager and doing a factory reset of the emulator is what fixed the problem for me.

[image]
[image]

You should have a similar option if you are using Android Studio. But if you would like to, you can try downloading and installing the [Xamarin Device Manager by Microsoft](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865528). It's an independent application that does not require installation of Visual Studio or Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

The misleading `ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8` when starting an Android Virtual Device (AVD) can occur when you have an old version of Android SDK installed, but without the Android Studio. The old standalone graphical SDK Manager is deprecated as of SDK Tools v25.2.3 - running it does not report any errors, but **does not properly update your Android SDK**.

Use the new command line SDK Manager `./sdkmanager --update` to properly update your Android SDK and the `e2fsck failed with exit code 8` problem will be gone.

More information: [How to update Android emulator without Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147699/how-to-update-android-emulator-without-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 756 M to 800 M

For this warning set Internal Storage = 756 MB
error warning will be removed.

Comment: How do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Change `disk.dataPartition.size` to `756M` in:

```
~/.android/avd/your_avd_name.avd/config.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and tried everything that is suggested above, without success.
Being desperate, I tried every menu I could find in AVD. So, I came on "show on disk" menu, at the right of the line of my device, in AVD device list.

Android Studio opened an explorer window, and showed me a directory with a name not matching my device name... Probably because I had renamed my device in AVD, and Android Studio had not reported this change on disk.

So I deleted my device, created a new one with same parameters, verified that directory and name matched, and launched the device... and it worked!!!

Hope this will be helpfull to anyone...

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here solved my issue, but I did find this after searching for a while and it solved my issue. If all else fails, check out the answer here:
[Emulator: ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005383/emulator-error-resizing-partition-e2fsck-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Comment: While link can contain useful information it is recommended to post answer details direct on SO.