# How to update Android emulator without Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I don't have Android Studio, just the Android SDK. When I launch one of my Android emulators using the Android Virtual Devices (AVD) Manager, I get the following message:

*Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio*.

[image: Starting Android Emulator dialog]

According to the steps, it seems that one could update the emulator even without Android Studio just by using the Android SDK Manager. But there is no SDK Tools tab.

[image]

Is the SDK Manager which is launched as a standalone application different from the SDK Manager available in the Android Studio?

Also, as you can see, everything is up-to-date and the version of Android SDK Tools is even newer than the one that is offered for downloading on the [Android website](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) (25.2.3 at the time of writing this question).

So how do I update the emulator? I don't need/want Android Studio.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The standalone GUI SDK Manager is deprecated as of [SDK Tools v25.2.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html).

The instructions you see in the "Starting Android Emulator" run window are specific to updating via Android Studio.  The SDK Manager inside of Android Studio is different than the standalone tool. We added new SDK packages that the old SDK Manager does not understand how to process nor update, including the new Emulator.

You have two ways going forward to update the emulator:

1. Use the new command line SDK Manager: `$ ./sdkmanager --update` [Read more here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)
2. Use the new [SDK Manager in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager)

Based on the window output, it also looks like your AVDs might be old, so you may want to create new AVDs or update for the latest features and better emulator performance & stability.

**SDK Tools Release Notes saying it has been deprecated:**
[image]

Comment: Where in the SDK Tools Release Notes that you have linked to can you see that it has been deprecated?

Comment: See this screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWK0F0x8GNDRkVkV01UOVplUVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: added the screenshot to the answer, just in case above link gets broken someday

Comment: It is difficult to update the SDK using the command line, as you need to run it from the tools\bin subfolder, which stops the update as it cannot move or delete the tools\ folder as part of the update. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796568/cant-update-tools-android-sdk-command-line-tools-for-windows for how to get around that stupidity.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to update Android emulator without Android Studio using what I previously described as the ["forced manual upgrade"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330)  and following the discussion in that post, I figured out some things concerning the standalone SDK:

> It seems the emulator (originally distributed
>   as part of the Android SDK Tools) is no longer updated since version
>   25.2.3

Thus the workaround involves a "**manual/forced upgrade**" of emulator tools. Currently I successfully upgraded to version 27.3.8 (and running Android 9 smoothly).

**The workaround**

Firstly make sure the **base packages** are still intact, and upgrade the emulator as follows:

**Instructions**

- Download the latest (or suitable emulator) from the links **supplied below**
- When done, decompress the downloaded emulator.zip file and extract the emulator package to `%USERPROFILE%\Android\android-sdk\tools` or **relevant path** (yes you have to **merge** it into that folder, since the emulator doesn't have all libraries and files)
- After this your emulator will be updated (to 27.3.8 in my case):

[image]

*<sup>Android SDK manager (GUI)</sup>*

Now prepare your AVD  as usual:

[image]

*<sup>Android AVD manager</sup>*

---

**Important links**

Base and Emulator tools(zip)

- [Android SDK base installer](https://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe) (offline windows)
- [Linux installer](https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz) (can use wget also)
- [Emulator version 27.3.8](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-4848055.zip) (linux)
- [Emulator version 27.3.8](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4848055.zip) (windows)
- [Emulator 27.3.8](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-4848055.zip) (mac os)
- [Emulator version 26.1.4](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4266726.zip) (windows)
- [Emulator version 26.1.4](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-4266726.zip) (linux)
- [Emulator version 27.1.10](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-4607264.zip) (mac os)
- [Emulator version 28.0.22](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-5194135.zip) (latest linux os latest)
- [Emulator version 28.0.22](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5194135.zip) (windows os  latest)
- [Emulator version 28.0.22](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-5194135.zip)(mac os latest)

  **Update: Added latest emulator versions**
- [Emulator version 29.0.11 (linux)](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-5598178.zip)
- [Emulator version 29.0.11 (windows)](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5598178.zip)
- [Emulator version 29.0.11 (macos)](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-5598178.zip)

Special thanks to [androiddev](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8xd1h1/android_emulator_2738_available_in_the_stable/) for providing links for linux, [eaglemt](https://github.com/eagletmt/) and [Vladyslav Panchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6108739/vladyslav-panchenko) for providing the links to repos and mostly important for mac os links.

---

Comment: Not sure how much time they will have this here, but: https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/AndroidSDK/. From Tencent, so I'd trust it. Links to many versions (maybe all versions?).

Answer (score 3):

This is what you can do to update to the most recent version that can be found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator

```
# go to your SDK directory
cd $ANDROID_HOME 

# remove old emulator version
rm -r emulator

# this will fetch the version from Canary channel
# keep in mind that this might be unstable
sdkmanager "emulator" --channel=3
```

For some reason this:

```
sdkmanager --install "emulator;31.2.6" --channel=3
```

did not work for me, that's why I had to remove the old version.