# Can't update \tools - Android SDK Command Line Tools for Windows

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I have just downloaded the Android SDK Command Line tools for Windows (26.0.2). I am attempting to download selected SDK components using \tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat, as well as updating \tools. The installation fails with the following message:

> Warning: An error occurred during installation: Failed to move away or delete existing target file: C:\testinstall\sdk\tools
>   Move it away manually and try again..

I don't see how I can remove \tools manually because it contains \bin\sdkmanager.bat.

Screenshot of the sdkmanager command:

[image]

All other components appear to install without error. See below for the components specified in my package file:

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line

Comment: I don't see how your reference is relevant @Radhey?

Comment: let me correct , you are trying to download sdk related stuff right !I thought http://stackoverflow.com/a/27060392/1848157 might be helpful .

Comment: @burntsugar You can directly download android studio with dependencies. The UI will give pretty good flexibility for modifications as well.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yeah that's quite funny. A way to do that is to copy the `tools` folder to another place (let's say `C:\temp\`). Then direct into the `C:\temp\tools\bin\`, open the cmd prompt there and run your update commands as such:

```
sdkmanager.bat --sdk_root=sdkRootPath --command
```

Where `sdkRootPath` is path to your original SDK folder (`C:\testinstall\sdk\`). Once that is done, delete the `C:\temp\tools\` copied folder.

Comment: Thank you, yes this worked. I reported an issue for this and was offered another solution which is basically the same thing. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38094997 "This is a known limitation of the current installation mechanism on windows"

Comment: Yeah I would definitely think so as in the previous versions of the sdk manager it was located at the root of the sdk folder, not inside the ```tools``` folder, hence there wasn't this issue of unable to delete, move or rename folders as much as we are facing with the new version right now. A design flaw that I hope will be delt with soon.

Comment: I get `access is denied` even though I have opened cmd as administrator

Comment: @JohnSmith could you post another question showing a screenshot of ur console and describing the steps you've taken and I'll be happy to help u there.

Comment: I was still having the problem with the update not being able to move/delete the tools folder. Turned out that Ihad a process, adb.exe from the Android SDK, which was running and had a lock on the tools folder, stopping other processes from doing anything with it.

Comment: Thanks @ahasbini I spent 1 and half day looking for its solution as there are not many articles directly referencing this particular type of issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You could temporarily rename to `tools.old`, run it to install new version in `tools` and then remove the old one.

```
cd YOUR-ANDROID-SDK-LOCATION
ren tools tools.old
tools.old\bin\sdkmanager.bat "tools"
dir tools*
del tools.old /q /s
tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --list
```

Answer (score 1):

it might be permission issue.Can you try doing sudo or if you on windows try to run terminal as administrator.

I have seen issues where the program is not able to delete the folder either due to lock or some weird reason.

Answer (score 1):

Run cmd in root c:.

```
c:\>testinstall\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --package_file=c:\testinstall\packx.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue on windows, I couldn't even rename the directory that is causing the issue.

I found out that adb was still running and ended the process and update/install worked fine without workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

The below command helped me to extract the SDK

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" --sdk_root=C:\AndroidSDK_RootLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the answer to your question but now, i can't exactly remeber the version, you can't update SDK tools directly or using Eclipse, sdk Manager, sdk.bat or android.bat, only way is to update them using Android Studio. It's Google's new policy, i read it somewhere, if i find the link i will share it

Answer (score 0):

My solution was as following:

1. Delete the Android SDK Tools via Android Studio (although it might complain it failed).
2. Close Android Studio
3. Manually delete `tools` folder from `C:\Users\<MyUsername>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` folder
4. Start Android Studio and then do the install of the Android SDK Tools via Android Studio.

Comment: Please remove the first two lines as they add no value to your answer.