# sdkmanager updatesdk on Windows not work

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I need to use the command line sdkmanager to update android tools. I must not use Android studio to do this.
However, if it works on Linux & Mac, it failed on Windows.
I received

"Warning: An error occurred during installation: Failed to move away or delete existing target file: C:\android-sdk\tools"

Why it doesn't work ?
Is there a way to perform this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this other question: [Can't update \tools - Android SDK Command Line Tools for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796568/cant-update-tools-android-sdk-command-line-tools-for-windows)

---

*Yeah that's quite funny. A way to do that is to copy the `tools` folder to another place (let's say `C:\temp\`). Then direct into the `C:\temp\tools\bin\`, open the cmd prompt there and run your update commands as such:*

```
sdkmanager.bat --sdk_root=sdkRootPath --command
```

*Where `sdkRootPath` is path to your original SDK folder (`C:\testinstall\sdk\`). Once that is done, delete the `C:\temp\tools\` copied folder.*

---