# How to accept android licenses after installing Tools for Cordova using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova, android-sdk-tools

I installed Visual Studio 2017 with the "Mobile development with JavaScript" option and "Android SDK setup" selected.
When I check Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Environment Variable Overrides I can see that ANDROID_HOME has been set to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25"

When I try to build my project I get an error:

> cordova-build error : > You have not accepted the license agreements
>   of the following SDK components: cordova-build error : [Android SDK
>   Platform 25].

I open a Windows command prompt and go to the directory containing the sdkmanager:

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25\tools\bin
```

I try `sdkmanager --licenses` but that results in

> Error: Unknown argument --licenses

So I try `sdkmanager --update` and that results in

> Warning: An error occurred during installation: Failed to move away or
>   delete existing target file:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25\tools Move it away manually and
>   try again.

So I move up to the folder above the tools folder and rename it:

```
ren tools tools.old
```

then try the update again:

```
tools.old\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

this gave me a warning:

> Warning: Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location
>   'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25\tools.old' (Expected
>   'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25\tools')

But after a lengthy wait the command reported that it was done and I could see that there was a new "tools" folder.

I tried to build my project again. Now my error is:

> Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update
>   your Android SDK.
>   Looked here:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47305199/150342

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

[You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39760172/150342)

Comment: Were you able to solve this @Colin?