# Visual Studio 2017 your emulator is out of date please update by launching android studio

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 (new installation) when I'm running the android emulator "VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone" I'm getting the message "Your emulator is out of date please update by launching android studio".

This message doesn't prevent me from running the application and only appears once every day (when I run VS for the first time)

So, how can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update Android emulator without Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147699/how-to-update-android-emulator-without-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

open your Android SDK Manager icon on Visual Studio toolbar. Check the Android SDK Tools and SDK Build Tools on Tools folder and then click Install Packages. But, I recommended you to use Genymotion Emulator