# How to determine the Android Max heap the vendor has set it to

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory

I have googled but can not seem to find out how to determine the max heap the Vendor has set the Android java heap to. I know how to get the max heap and the max heap you should use for a app from this great thread:
[Android heap size on different phones/devices and OS versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions)

But when I run these two methods and compare the results to what Android Studio Memory Profiler gc's at it is half the value of what the ActivityManager getMemoryClass says. So I suspect the Vendor set it lower than that value. I have a LG G4 and getMemoryClass indicates 256MB but I see GC's occur around 128MB.

Comment: Um, garbage collection does not wait until you reach the heap limit. After all, there are other apps on the device competing for the same memory.

Comment: Thanks, I know for the Oracle JVM it had a formula that seemed to indicate 90% of max when it collected. I see a nice sawtooth waveform but it never goes beyond 128MB. My App does use a lot of images that should go beyond the 128MB when I stress if but I never see that happen. I will look closely though.

Comment: I ran a stress test and sure enough there seems to be a hard limit at 128MB. I am trying to adjust for memory usage based on available Heap instead of having something from a config file. If the Vendor is setting the limit not based on the two methods mentioned in the link above I would like to know programmatically what that is.

Comment: I am wondering if the max heap means the java plus the native?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the `android:largeHeap` in your manifest. This flag indicates to the system that your app might need a bigger memory heap than that is allocated to a regular app. The system however takes the final call based on the overall memory size available on the device. Google doc says  -

> android:largeHeap
>
> Whether your application's processes should be
>   created with a large Dalvik heap. This applies to all processes
>   created for the application. It only applies to the first application
>   loaded into a process; if you're using a shared user ID to allow
>   multiple applications to use a process, they all must use this option
>   consistently or they will have unpredictable results. Most apps should
>   not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall
>   memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not
>   guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices
>   are constrained by their total available memory.
>
> To query the available memory size at runtime, use the methods
>   getMemoryClass() or getLargeMemoryClass().

So for your purpose, since you a need a bigger heap, this will definitely help.
Now this obviously does not answer the question, why `getMemoryClass` is returning 256 MB while garbage collection is happening at 128 MB (may be the system is keeping a too wide buffer). What I will suggest is you to print the return value of another method on `ActivityManager` which is `getLargeMemoryClass`. This along with turning `largeHeap` might provide some clues

Comment: I tried android:largeHeap and it did not cause the memory limit to change. I heard it is only a request and does not have to be honored by the device.  also did use getLargeMemoryClass and it returned 512MB or double getMemoryClass().

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I got the android:largeHeap="true" to work which is what I needed. Seems I had to put the following statements in my Main Activity class.
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.getLargeMemoryClass();