# How to increase y-axis on Memory Monitor in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-memory, android-monitor

The app that I'm working on uses a lot of memory and as soon as it starts, I see this blue brick wall. Is there any way I can increase the y-axis of the plot to go over the 169MB shown here?

[image]

Comment: What is the Java heap limit?

Comment: @AlLelopath, I don't know! How do I check?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions

Comment: I got it using Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory(), which equals 536870912