# how to get the heap size value?

Tags: android

How can I get the heap memory sizes of different processes running on emulator (or device) to my application (`Activity`) in Android?

Comment: This answer should do it in code.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android

Answer (score 8):

Open a command prompt, type

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo
```

or for jusr one process, either

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo xxx
```

where xxx is the PID

or

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo 'your apps package name'
```