# Android - determining Max Heap Size per App for a device

Tags: android, heap-memory

From one of Google's presentations, I came to know that the maximum Heap Size for the various hardwares are as follows - "Android G1 = 16MB, Droid = 24 MB, Nexus One = 32 MB, Xoom = 48 MB"

Is there a programmatic method to determine the maximum Heap Size per App, for an Android App on a specific hardware ?

Thanks.

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8bc8e36753538d0c) You need to call:
`long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();`