# Android devices, heap size

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory, heap-memory, ram

Currently my application works with android 2.1+ devices.
This app processes bitmaps. Sometimes I get OutOfMemory (eg. HTC G1 [16mb heap]).
I would like to specify this app for devices with min. 48mb heap.
It is impossible to set that in Manifest.xml but I thought about devices with android 2.3.3.
I could set minimum android 3.0 but 2.3.3 has over 38% devices.

What is the heap size for devices with stock android 2.3.3?

Answer (score 4):

Please refer these links :

[Manifest Heap-Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)

[Devices Heap-Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions)

[Another Heap-Size Explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460441/android-devices-with-small-heap)

Some Google and stackoverflow search.