# getView from ImageAdaptar GridLayout - OutofMemoryError

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory, grid-layout

I having the "out of memory" error on my ImageAdapter, I tried some solutions reusing the ImageView, but not works, I hope any can help me :)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { 
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);//Creamos la imagen sólo si no existe
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;//Sino reusamos el objeto
    }

    //Todas con el mismo ancho
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

I have some app similar, but not this problem, for sure on this I have 290 diferent images, and the other app I have only one :), I thought that the convertView == null fix the outOfMemory problems

More info:
- Only 20 images have more of 100kb, only 3 of these are >500k and <900k

PD: Im using this tutorial code: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Thanks for your help guys and sorry my english

Answer (score 0):

The Android programs are far more complex than most, images seem to take up considerably more memory in Ram than they do on the disk. Not withstanding, there is one thing which you can easily do, and a few other tips.

1. Add `android:largeHeap="true"` to your application tag in your manifest.
2. Run some sort of a memory profiler to look for leaks.
3. Delete any unused variables.
4. Make some variables static, if they are used consistently across classes.
5. Try to use the correctly sized images.

Also, take a look at [How can I gracefully degrade my performance, given limited memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9986385/544198)