# Dalvik memory allocation

Tags: java, android, memory-management, dalvik

Is there any way, how to **programatically** (like allocating and filling some array) check, how much memory can Dalvik allocate before `OutOfMemoryError` appears? Is it possible to do it with Java?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks, I know, there is one row solution, but I need to verify it manually... that's why I am asking for programatically solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every Java application allocates memory when it runs. This is what we have done using

```
java -Xms<initial heap size> -Xmx<maximum heap size>.
```

Also, in Throwable block, you can do the following way:

1. Total Memory (heap) - Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
2. System.out.println("Used Memory:"
           + (runtime.totalMemory() - Runtime.runtime.freeMemory()) / mb);
3. System.out.println("Free Memory:"
           + Runtime.runtime.freeMemory() / mb);
4. System.out.println("Total Memory:" + runtime.totalMemory() / mb);

Maybe this will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, but problem is with field allocation. I am using String array to determine actual allocated memory, when I set big value, my program crashes. Do you know, how to create dynamic string array without need of implicit size declaration?

Comment: In Java, you can create an arraylist and that can be converted to an Array like this: List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); al.add("your string"); al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);. However, in this situation also, if memory is a constraint, it will crash.