# Android OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget while loading images

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

I am using an Image Loader which loads the image from the URL and caches in into my file system. I am finding the following crash reports from few phones using ACRA

**Error:**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
    at com.m7.nomad.utils.ImageLoader.decodeFile(ImageLoader.java:117)
    at com.m7.nomad.utils.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:88)
    at com.m7.nomad.utils.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:68)
    at com.m7.nomad.utils.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:170)
```

**ImageLoader.java**

```
package com.m7.nomad.utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import com.m7.nomad.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        // Make the background thread low priority because it will not affect
        // the
        // UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);

        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.image_place_holder;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
        // This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be
        // some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them.
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        // start thread if it's not started yet
        if (photoLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 65;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            /*
             * while (true) { if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp /
             * 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) break; width_tmp /= 2; height_tmp /= 2; scale
             * *= 2; }
             */

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue = new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread() {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    // stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad = new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        // removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image) {
            for (int j = 0; j < photosToLoad.size();) {
                if (photosToLoad.get(j).imageView == image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    // thread waits until there are any images to load in the
                    // queue
                    if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() == 0)
                        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() != 0) {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                            photoToLoad = photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
                        if (tag != null && tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)) {
                            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp,
                                    photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView
                                    .getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if (Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread = new PhotosLoader();

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i) {
            bitmap = b;
            imageView = i;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (bitmap != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

This is how i call the ImageLoader

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.context);
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(imagePath, new Activity(), image);
```

Comment: how to call your url with imagedownloader class?

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya i have edited my question with that code

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14117007/1935890

Comment: imagepath your url and image is imageView right?

Comment: what about imagesize are big?

Comment: @HarshaMV Use BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize. set it to >1 which scales down.(set higher val)

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya my images are 900*600. yeah u are right

Comment: @Sathish didnt quite get you. can you please explain

Comment: @HarshaMV You are trying to load large image file. Use bitmap.option methods to scale down original image by some factor say 5, so it will req. less amount of memory. and hence will not cause error.

Comment: @Sathish i checked that scaling factor. the image width becomes too small to be displayed. my images are 900x600 and on tablets it takes close to 525dp of height on a 7inch tablet. on a phone it takes 325dp height. how to achieve this ?

Comment: @Sathish also this happens only few phones mainly the LG and Sony Erricson phone acorrding to the Crash Report. So is there any way to  run a GC to clear it off the memory. and where should i use it

Comment: So much code, a issue that has just too many duplicates.