# OutofMemoryError in android while creating a bitmap from string path?

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I have a service using which i am changing android wallpaper. I am passing path of images to the service and then using following code to set the image as wallpaper:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        final String imagePath[] = mSelectedImgPath.split(",");
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < imagePath.length; i++) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath[i]);
                this.setWallpaper(bitmap);
                Thread.sleep(1000 * time);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
01-25 15:59:12.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-149
    01-25 15:59:12.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    01-25 15:59:12.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    01-25 15:59:12.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
    01-25 15:59:12.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:299)
    01-25 15:59:12.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:324)
    01-25 15:59:12.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at com.wallpaper.demo.WallpaperChangeService.run(WallpaperChangeService.java:55)
    01-25 15:59:12.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to resize your bitmap image and set as wallpaper.

Comment: I am resizing the images before setting them as wallpaper as per the device screen size. I thing the issue is related to something else.

Comment: I don't think so. the Log is clearly telling you, that you ran out-of-memory by trying to decode the Bitmap from its path. You should try to decode it with bounds, or maybe giving BitmapOptions a compression level lower than 100

Comment: have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14117007/1070711 , hope this will give you some hint about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your **"VM heap"** if your running program in emulator.
Goto avd manager and click on to ur android emulator and increase size VM heap.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your images might be in big size, try to scale your images.

refer this [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

just after entering the loop

```
  for (int i = 0; i < imagePath.length; i++) {
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath[i]);
            this.setWallpaper(bitmap);
            Thread.sleep(1000 * time);
        }
```