# android load image to maximum allowable size

Tags: android, canvas

I am making a drawing app such that user can choose to load pictures from the gallery and further draw on it. However, if the size of the photo is greater than the screen, it can only show part of the picture.

```
   public void load_pic(String picturePath) // load a picture from gallery
   {
      bitmap = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
      bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
      invalidate();
   }
```

How could i code such that the picture can either

1. load in such that can fit either maximium allowable screen width or height, or
2. load in such that can pull the image to occupy the full screen

Also, running on some device it would give out `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`...and it crashed...How could that be tackled?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14117007/1935890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find the screen width and height which you can accomplish by using below code.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int newWidth = display.getWidth();
int newHeight = display.getHeight();
```

If you are not in activity you can get the display as describe below,

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContex.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

You can scale the bitmap using below code.

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oldBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

You can also set the height and width at the time of the decoding using,
[outWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#outWidth) and outHeight attribute of the [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html).

And to overcome the `outOfMemoryError` you can refer the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14117007/1070711) pointed in comment.

P.S. I wrote that linked answer.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your advice!! yet the panel underlines the getWindowManager() for stating The method getWindowManager() is undefined... =(

Comment: you need to pass the context to access the method if you are not in activity. See the updated answer.

Comment: thanks!!! but i have changed to be bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

Comment: by using this logic, quality of bitmap reduced!