# Android Getting scaled image file length

Tags: android, file, bitmap, out-of-memory, scale

Here is my problem: 
I'm asking my user to choose between different sizes of a same image in order to upload it. 
My interface shows 4 buttons with each giving informations about the width, the height of the image, and the length of the file.
I managed to produce the four versions of the image calling **Bitmap.createScaledBitmap**, then compressing those bitmaps to files again.
I'm well aware I need to recycle the bitmap and delete the files when I'm done.

However, when trying to compute a big file, the method **createScaledBitmap** throws an out of memory exception.
I was told to use the option **inJustDecodeBounds** to decode the file but it would return a null bitmap.

Does someone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Here is the code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bmp = getScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri, options), ratio);

private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap bmp, float ratio) {
    int srcWidth = bmp.getWidth();
    int srcHeight = bmp.getHeight();
    int dstWidth = (int)(srcWidth * ratio);
    int dstHeight = (int)(srcHeight * ratio);
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
    bmp.recycle();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552076/android-bitmap-createscaledbitmap-throws-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-mostly-on-je . I am not sure if it would help, but I suggest you look at the answers there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Bitmap.createScaledBitmap throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError mostly on Jelly Bean 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552076/android-bitmap-createscaledbitmap-throws-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-mostly-on-je)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your replies, I don't consider it to be a duplicate. I previously found the thread you linked but it's quite old and it didn't solve my problem.

Anyway, I solved the problem.

I first tried using **Glide** library which is said to be better for memory management. Though, there was an improvement but it wasn't perfect and the problem occured again.

Using **android:largeHeap="true"** put an end to my nightmare. This has to be set in the application field of your manifest.

I hope this will help someone else.