# Clear background after start new activity

Tags: android, background, resources

I had a problem with lack of memory thus I decided to clean the background before starting a new activity.

It works, but I have the bad side-effect that I have a black screen before a new activity is started.

This is my code:

I set it here:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    bg.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg, sizeWigth, sizeHeight)));

}
```

I clear it here:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    bg.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    System.gc();
}
```

Have you any idea to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you just use `bg.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.bg);`? Or better yet, why don't you set it in XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you loading large image make sure you follow following rules

1. Load the image based on your Screen DPI. if your screen is small their no reason load a huge image into memory.
2. Bitmap Sampling. read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for Sub-sampling a large image
3. Monitor your HeapSize and make you have enough space after loading the image to do other processing. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android)
4. load image using java references. Make sure to reload the image when it is null. This will help you to avoid out of memory issue.

   System.gc();

is a hints to garbage collector and and their are no guarantee that garbage collector will collect garbage after execution of this line.

Putting this image on XML layout will not help you with memory issue.