# How can I retrieve the max heap available on device?

Tags: android, android-manifest, heap-memory

I have a problem. My app use 20MB of ram so I want to avoid mobile phone that have heap less than 20MB.
I tried with Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory() but this function retrieve me the wrong result (256MB on SGS3) because I want to retrieve the available heap for a single app.

How can I detect it?
There is an attribute in the manifest?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `getMemoryClass`

```
 ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();
```

it returns the approximate per-application memory class of the current device.