# App Crashes in the Emulator even after sampling the Bitmap image

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-image

I am testing my App in the Emulator.
Emulator Device Size - 480 x 854
Image size - 1280 x 720
Sample size = 1 (This is from the process explained in the Android reference - http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

When I trigger this activity the App goes fine, When I traverse to next activity and come back, the App crashes with OOM. I have followed the process explained in the android manual for loading the bitmap efficiently, but still it fails in the line
    backgoundImage = getAssetImage(getApplicationContext(),"backgroundhomepage"); 
Kindly assist.

Question 1 : What will be the minimum heap size for this sized devices ? 
Question 2 : Do I need to change the sample size ? 
Question 3 : Any other steps I need to follow ?

### Code:

```
    /**************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    1.  To get the image from asset library
     **************************************************************************************************************************************************************/ 

    public  Bitmap getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
        AssetManager assets = getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream buffer = null;
        try {
            buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
        options.inPurgeable = true;  


        Log.i("DragDrop", " 1280 x 800 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 1280, 800) );
        Log.i("DragDrop", " 1024 x 600 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 1024, 600) );
        Log.i("DragDrop", " 480 x 800 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 480, 800) ); 
        Log.i("DragDrop", " 480 x 854 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 480, 854) ); 
        Log.i("DragDrop", " 1280 x 720 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 1280, 720) );
        Log.i("DragDrop", " 720 x 1280 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 720, 1280) );
        Log.i("DragDrop", " 240 x 432 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 240, 432) ); 
        Log.i("DragDrop", " 240 x 400 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 240, 400) ); 
        Log.i("DragDrop", " 320 x 480 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 320, 480) ); 
        Log.i("DragDrop", " 240 x 320 "  + calculateInSampleSize(options, 240, 320) ); 

        if (tabletSize) {
            Log.i("DragDrop", "am tablet");   
        } else {
            Log.i("DragDrop", "am phone");  
            Log.i("DragDrop", "------------------------------------------------------");  
            Log.i("DragDrop", "dWidth"  + dWidth); 
            Log.i("DragDrop", "dHeight" + dHeight);  
            int tempSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, (int)dWidth, (int)dHeight);  
            Log.i("DragDrop", "sample size" + tempSampleSize + "so options left aside" );  
            if (tempSampleSize > 1) { 
                Log.i("DragDrop", "sample size > 1"  + "so options is set to the sample size " + tempSampleSize ); 
                options.inSampleSize = tempSampleSize;
            }
            //options.inSampleSize = 2; 
        }


        Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer, null, options);
        Bitmap finalImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, (int) dWidth, (int) dHeight, true);
        //temp.recycle();
      //    temp=null; 
        return finalImage;   

    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = 720;
        final int width = 1280;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

### LogCat:

```
07-07 21:16:17.960: I/DragDrop(694):  1280  800 1
07-07 21:16:17.960: I/DragDrop(694):  1024  600 1
07-07 21:16:17.970: I/DragDrop(694):  480  800 1
07-07 21:16:18.001: I/DragDrop(694):  480  854 1
07-07 21:16:18.001: I/DragDrop(694):  1280  720 1
07-07 21:16:18.001: I/DragDrop(694):  720  1280 1
07-07 21:16:18.040: I/DragDrop(694):  240  432 2
07-07 21:16:18.040: I/DragDrop(694):  240  400 2
07-07 21:16:18.040: I/DragDrop(694):  320  480 2
07-07 21:16:18.060: I/DragDrop(694):  240  320 2
07-07 21:16:18.122: I/DragDrop(694): am phone
07-07 21:16:18.122: I/DragDrop(694): ------------------------------------------------------
07-07 21:16:18.130: I/DragDrop(694): dWidth854.0
07-07 21:16:18.170: I/DragDrop(694): dHeight480.0
07-07 21:16:18.170: I/DragDrop(694): sample size1so options left aside
07-07 21:16:19.080: D/dalvikvm(694): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 38% free 9526K/15175K, paused 516ms, total 534ms
07-07 21:16:19.250: I/dalvikvm-heap(694): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.866MB for 3686416-byte allocation
07-07 21:16:19.540: D/dalvikvm(694): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 13126K/15175K, paused 280ms, total 280ms
07-07 21:16:19.990: I/Choreographer(694): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-07 21:16:20.370: D/dalvikvm(694): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 14% free 13127K/15175K, paused 114ms+120ms, total 830ms
07-07 21:16:21.150: I/Choreographer(694): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-07 21:16:21.980: D/dalvikvm(694): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 17K, 14% free 13112K/15175K, paused 647ms, total 647ms
07-07 21:16:21.980: I/dalvikvm-heap(694): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1639696-byte allocation
07-07 21:16:22.250: I/mybringback(694): In Pause of mybringback
07-07 21:16:22.250: D/dalvikvm(694): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 14% free 13112K/15175K, paused 262ms, total 262ms
07-07 21:16:22.263: E/dalvikvm-heap(694): Out of memory on a 1639696-byte allocation.
07-07 21:16:22.270: I/dalvikvm(694): "Thread-82" prio=5 tid=14 RUNNABLE
07-07 21:16:22.312: I/dalvikvm(694):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=041354480 self=02a1b35c8
07-07 21:16:22.312: I/dalvikvm(694):   | sysTid=850 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=706426136
07-07 21:16:22.320: I/dalvikvm(694):   | schedstat=( 768726126 3420053317 119 ) utm=62 stm=14 core=0
07-07 21:16:22.320: I/dalvikvm(694):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
07-07 21:16:22.320: I/dalvikvm(694):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
07-07 21:16:22.330: I/dalvikvm(694):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:586)
07-07 21:16:22.340: I/dalvikvm(694):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:466)
07-07 21:16:22.340: I/dalvikvm(694):   at com.eample.funandlearn.DragDrop$MyBringBackSurface.getAssetImage(DragDrop.java:551)
07-07 21:16:22.340: I/dalvikvm(694):   at com.eample.funandlearn.DragDrop$MyBringBackSurface.run(DragDrop.java:633)
07-07 21:16:22.350: I/dalvikvm(694):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-07 21:16:22.400: W/dalvikvm(694): threadid=14: thread eiting with uncaught eception (group=0
07-07 21:16:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(694): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-82
07-07 21:16:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(694): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-07 21:16:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
07-07 21:16:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
07-07 21:16:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:586)
07-07 21:16:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:466)
07-07 21:16:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at com.eample.funandlearn.DragDrop$MyBringBackSurface.getAssetImage(DragDrop.java:551)
07-07 21:16:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at com.eample.funandlearn.DragDrop$MyBringBackSurface.run(DragDrop.java:633)
07-07 21:16:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(694): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-07 21:16:30.820: I/Process(694): Sending signal. PID: 694 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your heap size like this

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
Log.v("onCreate", "maxMemory:" + Long.toString(maxMemory));
```

Source : [Detect application heap size in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android)
For other questions i dont help you. Sorry.

Comment: This is not always good as this will use the memory which may be needed for other apps. I welcome any other answer

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this simple code to get any image from the gallery app sure with the correct image orientation.

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(
                            getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
            System.out.println("The Quality is" + quality);
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmp = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(
                            getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] orientationColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cur = managedQuery(imageFileUri, orientationColumn, null,
                null, null);
        int orientation = -1;
        if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
            orientation = cur.getInt(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
        }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(orientation);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        view.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

you are welcome to use it.