# Android openGL: handle large dataset (Point cloud ) in array

Tags: android, opengl-es, point-clouds

Now I have more than 3 million points to deal with. I am using `openGL` and it's `verticesbuffer` to store them. so, the vertices array will be roughly 9 million elements( each point has x,y,z). When I load them into float array, it crashed app by throwing `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception. 
I tried to split up it into several arrays, but how do I draw them one after another in a single render? or create multiple renders to deal with different vertices array?
Here is my render class

```
public class Render implements Renderer{

private Points points;

public Render( ){
   //do nothing 
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame( final GL10 gl ) {

    gl.glClear( GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.glLoadIdentity();    

    points.draw(gl);

}


@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged( final GL10 gl, final int width, final int height ) {

    gl.glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );   
    gl.glMatrixMode( GL10.GL_PROJECTION );  
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    


    GLU.gluPerspective( gl, 125.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 50f, 500f );

    gl.glMatrixMode( GL10.GL_MODELVIEW ); 
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated( final GL10 gl, final EGLConfig config ) {

      /**pass Point array to points class */    
    points = new Points( arrayPoints );

}
```

here is my Points class

```
private float[] vertices;

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

public Points( final float[] pointsArray ){

    this.vertices=pointsArray;

    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( vertices.length *4 );
    byteBuf.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );
    vertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put( vertices );
    vertexBuffer.position( 0 );
}


public void draw( final GL10 gl ) {     
    gl.glEnableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

    /**point size*/
    gl.glPointSize(1);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, vertices.length/3);
    gl.glDisableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're likely overflowing the heap size.  Newer phones have a max heap size of something like 256MB.  That's the max size for one application.

You can find more details about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android/9428660#9428660).

A solution would be to store these alternatively - do you really need to display 9 million vertices explicitly?  Can you stream them somehow?

Comment: I think I need to display them all. they are geomorphic data. User should be able to view them in detail. What do you mean by stream them? could you give more details?

Comment: Show a limited resolution of them at a "zoomed out" level and show more detail with a limited scope at a "zoomed in" level.  Think how google maps shows streets - when you view the whole country, you only see highways, but when you zoom in, you see everything.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use NDK. There is no strict memory limitation.

Comment: I am using ndk to read all points. Do you mean use openGL in native code?

Comment: Do not attempt to load large data set in Java. Do all processing in NDK, including OpenGL calls.