# Why does a simple Service use more memory after a while?

Tags: android, memory, service

I created a simple service example. When I start the service it uses **6.6MB** or more. Some time later it increases automatically. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183549/ram-increase-android-service) link but found no solution. How can I confirm how much the RAM usage increased?

[image: Service used ram]

**Service class**

```
public class MyTestService extends Service {
public MyTestService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("MyTestService", "onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    Log.e("MyTestService", "onLowMemory");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("MyTestService", "onBind");
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e("MyTestService", "onStartCommand");
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("MyTestService", "onDestroy");
}
}
```

**Activity class** where i only start & stop service

**1. OnStartService**

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyTestService.class));
```

**2. OnStopService**

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyTestService.class));
```

**Manifiest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sample.service">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ServiceCheckActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyTestService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory usage usually increases because of lingering objects, which is not garbage collected yet, causing sawtooth - like plot in ddms. Android manages Service's lifecycle, so if it is empty, maybe you should not worry about it. For avoiding that consider using 'Flyweight' design pattern, if you need to create a lot of temporary objects.