# How to check available heap size programatically for my android application?

Tags: android

I wants to know the available heap size at runtime because when I was loading images,it is running out of memory error.

For checking my memory leaks I want to know the heapsize at some particular breakpoints.

Can anyone tell me how to get the available heap size left for my application programatically.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
Debug.getNativeHeapSize()
```

the `debug` class hve number of methods for tracking allocations

Answer (score 0):

Use ActivityManager.[getMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) or  `getLargeMemoryClass ()`.  This returns approximate amount of memory you are allowed to use, in megabytes.

Use `getApplication().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)` to get the activity manager.

Comment: I wants to know available space left in my heap everytime when I call  webservices,so that I can understand whether my ImageLoader class is occupying my heap or not